# How did Stack Overflow come to know about dummy upvotes?

Tags: discussion, support, tactical-upvoting

I and my friend are both members of Stack Overflow.  I told my friend to vote me up.  He upvoted almost all of my questions and answers.  I got almost 150 upvotes.  On the next day, when I visited Stack Overflow, I found my reputation as it had been before the upvotes.

How does Stack Overflow identify, differentiate, and track dummy/unnecessary upvotes?

Comment: So...you admit that you tried to cheat? ;)

Comment: Just so that I can sleep tonight... was the other user Jon Skeet?

Comment: What? There's no `collusion` tag?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

statistics!

In fact, we have a whole community who does nothing but help us figure out statistical anomalies in voting.

Say Hi to them at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Wow. What an interesting way to promote a SE site! :)

Comment: @sugar: Because someone has answered it and the answer has an upvote.

Comment: Because another anomalie has been detected probably.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: @sugar, why, trying to hide the evidence when it's too late? :) (http://www.thefirstpost.co.uk/65917,news-comment,news-politics,gillian-mckeith-ben-goldacre-and-the-vanishing-tweets-libel)