# Create another user to upvote?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to “cheat” on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97887/is-it-possible-to-cheat-on-se-sites)

Before I ask my question, I'm going to make clear that I am *not* going to do this, I just want to know if it's possible.

Is it possible to make another user with a different account or a different e-mail and just upvote your original account's answers and questions? I know the community user keeps track of downvotes, but does it keep track of upvotes?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. No, it is not allowed. This is an offense that can lead to banning if it is detected by the moderators or an automatic script.

Comment: Serial upvoting is automatically detected by the system, so there's really no point in even trying.

Comment: @animuson Yeah, I thought I told you I wasn't going to. Thanks for the clarification everyone!

Comment: No, it is not possible.  We have super secret tools which can identify users sockpuppeting.  Even seven proxies won't save you.

Comment: Are the seven Dobermans watching the gate a secret, or can I freely speak of them?

Comment: I can see why it got closed, but I clarified at the beginning that I wouldn't do it. So you guys don't have to keep telling me that it's against the rules. I'm not discrediting your answers everyone, but I'm just letting you know.

Comment: It got closed because it's a duplicate. No one is *accusing* you of doing it, or even thinking about doing it. You asked if it would work, and if it was allowed. It would, but it's not. The answers to the duplicate say precisely that. Don't take offense at closure of questions as a duplicate. That helps keep the site clean and all the info in one place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called using a sock puppet and it is **highly** frowned upon. It's abuse of the system. It's possible, but definitely in no way recommended. People have been banned for this.

Comment: And yes, the Community user (for want of a better name for the process that actually does this) keeps track of it.