# Is SO upvote abuse possible?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, abuse

Is this situation possible:

1. Someone have 2 accounts with "upvote" privilege and one question.
2. He creates new (unprivileged) account and posts some (even meaningless) answer to this question.
3. Answer gets 2 upvotes from privileged accounts and new account gets "upvote" privilege, which can be used to raise reputation of two initial accounts.
4. New (now privileged) account deletes his answer but retains reputation gained from it.
5. Goto step 2.

Even if phantom accounts lose their privileges (via moderation), initial accounts will not (at least it looks like). So you can automate this process and create trusted account in virtually no time, can't you?

You can even try to abuse edits of original question, approved by question owner.

I know I can verify this easily by hand, I just don't want to get banned for abuse if it turns out possible.

UPDATE: I've just got banned for 3 days on SO :-).

Comment: Your step 4 premise is false: reputation accrued from deleted posts is *not* retained.

Comment: @dlev - it is until a recalculation is performed. So as long as there's no recalculation you keep the reputation.

Comment: @ChrisF Good point. It would likely *eventually* be taken care of, but not necessarily any time soon.

Comment: @ChrisF - when this recalculation is performed, can you provide some details?

Comment: @Andrei - it's performed manually from the `/reputation` page, or by a moderator when they feel necessary, or when your account is unsuspended.

Comment: @Andrei: It can be done manually be going to stackoverflow.com/reputation and clicking on recalc at the bottom or at pre-defined intervals on SO. I doubt it is done every day on SO because that would probably be an expensive DB operation for all users.

Comment: @0A0D: I'm pretty sure it is *not* done automatically on any schedule. The developers did a global rep recalc once or twice and freaked everyone completely out because a bunch of people lost a bunch of points. Moderators can invoke a reputation recalc on individual users for special circumstances, though.

Comment: Enough deleted posts and you are automatically banned from posting.

Comment: @Wont - you just need one for each new account.

Comment: @Won't_: It does apply for answers?

Comment: @Cody: Yes, sorry that's what I meant by pre-defined time. I remember that global recalc - I think it happened this year right?

Comment: @Won't: Now I would be interested if you got notifications for the above two comments by Andrei and genesis `:-)`

Comment: Well, Andrei I think you got your answer. You were banned for 3 days :)

Comment: @0A0D - Looks like you can use this scenario to ban your enemies.

Comment: How exactly could this be deployed as a weapon against your "enemies"? (And why, pray tell, do you have "enemies" on a *Q&A site*?)

Comment: @Andrei: Only if you upvote your enemies enough to give them voting privileges, they upvote you a lot in return, and they happen to be at the same IP address as you.

Comment: @Hendrik: Why wouldn't he? Only the first 3 characters of the name have to match. That's `Won`; good enough.

Comment: Yes, [it is possible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60515/how-did-stack-overflow-come-to-know-about-dummy-upvotes), [but don't come complaining that your rep is gone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75032/5k-reputation-loss-in-one-day-how-big-is-that).

Comment: @Cody - this is only theoretical question. You can pose things as if it's someone else uses sockpuppets and got his account banned for, say, purely destructive reasons.

Comment: @Cody Probably not, since the comments didn't just say `Won`. When more than 3 characters are used, they will all be used in the matching (per rule #3 [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020)).

Comment: @0A0D: nice one xD

Comment: @Anno let's test!

Comment: @JNK No notification, as expected.

Comment: @Cody: At [this answer by Michael Mrozek](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101824/are-these-questions-exact-duplicates/101827#101827), I found it very useful that it's not just the first three characters that matter. So I was able to differentiate between MichaelM an MichaelP. (Not the best of examples since MichaelM is the post owner, but I hope it's clear what I mean.)

Comment: @Won't : : It does apply for answers?

Comment: Doesn't sound hypothetical at all

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While it might be possible in the short term there are tools that moderators have at their disposal to spot this sort of behaviour.

Once spotted it's dealt with by account merging, suspension and/or deletion (as appropriate).

Comment: Gained upvotes can be used to raise reputation of totally unrelated account. What will you do with this account?

Comment: @Andrei When accounts are merged, votes made by one of them will be invalidated.

Comment: We can spot these early on if we're tipped off, or have time to check on voting irregularities. If I strongly suspect something is fishy, my motivation to spend 30 minutes digging increases quite a bit. Every sock puppet is a slap in the face to an honest user who works hard to be helpful, I have very little tolerance for it.

Answer (score 2):

A reputation recalculation will eventually take care of the deletion concern. You can try to game the system but I have confidence in the community members that poor answers or answers that don't answer the question well enough will get downvoted so all that effort will eventually be wasted. The system is able to correct itself for this not to be a major concern. And anyways, rep is "imaginary points" that is not cashable for real money so this is all just for honor and personal pride. Oh and the fact that you like to learn and help other people.

Comment: The part about "rep is imaginary anyway" is silly -- it doesn't translate to real money, but that doesn't mean letting somebody exploit their way to 10k is a good idea, it has meaning

Comment: @Michael: I'd like to see someone exploit their way to 10K because I have a hard enough time making 200 points per day (though I have been doing pretty good lately - 1,000 points to go), but my answers and questions are legit.

Comment: @Michael: My point is that everyone gets all bent out of shape over something that probably will happen in .000001% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from moderation there is also an automatic system which spots suspicious patterns, this was noted [on the stackexchange blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's considered exploiting their system. The entire network of Stack Exchange is about sharing of information and paying it forward with reputation scores. Being in the technical field, you can also reference this site for employers to see how active you are in your field of interest thus also giving you an edge in the job market.

Creating an imaginary film over your profile via exploiting the reputation point system is considered "Illegal" in the Stack Exchange community and your profiles can and will be handled with due-diligence if you are caught.

Comment: Plus, why waste all the time to fake it when you can use the same amount of time just learning information and giving back to the community. It's pretty shameful.