# Reputation reduced by more than 400 points

Tags: support, reputation

I was reaching almost 1000 points and suddenly my reputation went down by more than 400 points.

When I checked my reputation history, no points seemed to have been deducted. What might be the cause of this drop in reputation?

Comment: Did you check the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of your reputation list?

Comment: Go to your [profile's reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1225432/chinna-82?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=1) and check "show removed posts" at the bottom, to see if you recently lost reputation from posts that were deleted.

Comment: nope..i dindt delete any post..and I checked show removed posts..no post removed...

Comment: Massive rep loss like this is *usually* a sign of vote fraud getting busted, but this looks like a legit user. With bounties and all. Maybe a mod can take a look to see what happened?

Comment: Any kind of help is highly appreciated. I really didn't care much on gaining back the point. I'm more interested why my point was reduced. If it mistake from my side i will improve in future. Thanks

Comment: And you swear you [did not anything fishy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75032/5k-reputation-loss-in-one-day-how-big-is-that)?

Comment: Fishy..? I dont get you. This is just a point. If you found something, do let me know. Maybe i can learn up.

Comment: Fishy...like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12510965/1026459

Comment: @TravisJ what Fishy about it? I dont get it. I still finding a way how i can achieve this.No upvote given for the post as well. Can you please explain where i did wrong.?

Comment: @TravisJ: I thought more along the lines of "[Well, you know...my questions were so seldom upvoted, I asked a friend to do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60515/how-did-stack-overflow-come-to-know-about-dummy-upvotes)" kind of fishy.

Comment: I would also go for vote fraud that was detected and dealt with automatically. Maybe somebody was upvoting your questions serially (without even you knowing about it) and at some point the system identified this.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That would seem to agree with the 8 Popular Question badges, 5 of which are sitting at a score of 0 currently. OP: did those questions previously have high scores? It could very well be possible that you somehow got included into a voting ring without your knowledge. If all those accounts that were voting you up got merged, all of those duplicate votes would've gotten destroyed.

Comment: @chinna_82: See, that's I meant with fishy!

Comment: ermm..i have no idea whats going on... from now not going to focus on points...just the question and the answer.

Answer (score 14):

When you engage in sock puppet voting behavior, we will reverse those votes and merge the users.

Comment: stupid question: does that result in any particular notifications to the user? That is, beyond the obvious drop in rep?

Comment: @Bart It usually results in a suspension, which is announced with a moderator message. If that doesn't happen, merges are silent.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for that. Good to know.